# net-ssh and remote environment

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I want to execute some remote command on my server using net-ssh library.

I have the following example:

```
Net::SSH::start(host, user, options = {:keys => '~/.ssh/id_rsa'}) do |ssh|
  puts ssh.exec!("echo $PATH")
  ssh.loop
end
```

The result is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

My problem is that I have not my PATH loaded as it should be.

I should also have some RVM paths, and custom paths defining into my .zshrc.

How could I change this behavior to let net-ssh to use my .zshrc to load my default environment ?

**Solution:**

```
puts ssh.exec!("source ~/.zshrc; echo $PATH")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tried something like:

```
ssh.exec!("source /home/you/.zshrc")
puts ssh.exec!("echo $PATH")
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Each exec! command are independent. That means that the environment is reset each time.
I've updated my question explain how I solved the problem. But thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Found a way around this problem, actually. It's quite nice solution. Thanks to Vald for telling me that every exec is independent of itself, so then you can just use && to link the commands together.

For example, I have a ruby script that is runnable, and I'm using zsh, so I just use this:

```
ssh.exec("source .zshrc && ./backup.rb")
```

Works like a charm! Of course you can also be on the safe side and use the full path or ~, but it gets the job done.

Edit: Sorry, also just saw you put a solution above. Is there a difference between using `;` and `&&`?

Comment: When using `&&`, the second will only fire if the first succeeds. When using `;`, the second command will fire regardless of the exit code of the first.

Comment: Yep. Learned that eventually haha

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Net/SSH for running multiple commands.

Try [net-ssh-session](https://github.com/sosedoff/net-ssh-session).

Commands are not independent and it loads your user's env vars.