# How to access commands in bin folder through ruby net-ssh?

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I'm using net-ssh to connect to my server and need to run some ruby command.

The following doesn't work:

```
puts ssh.exec!("ruby -v")
bash: ruby: command not found
```

I always need to specify the full path:

```
puts ssh.exec!("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -v")
```

And it's like that for other command in general (rvm etc.)

Is there any option that would load the commands present in the bin folders?

Comment: I've tried that on my machine. But everything works fine. Is there something wrong with the server? Say, maybe have a try "ssh.exec 'echo $PATH'"?

Comment: What's the output of `ssh.exec!("echo $PATH")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[net-ssh and remote environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854055/net-ssh-and-remote-environment)

you need to source .bashrc/.zshrc/ etc

`ssh.exec!("source ~/.zshrc; /usr/bin/env ruby -v")`

Comment: great thanks! I would add that here is what you need in order to script something: https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting/