# Cant run Ruby script via gem "ssh-net"

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am using gem [net-ssh](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/).

The connection is established. I am able to run some simple scripts(like "pwd", "ls", etc.) successfully, but when I run the "restart" script I get an error.

Here is a snippet:

```
output = ssh.exec!("cd /home/csrhub/git/csrhub-api; ./bin/restart")
puts "#{output}"
```

And the output:

> ./bin/restart:7:in `exec': No such file or directory - bundle (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from ./bin/restart:7:in`'
>   Environment determined as "development" based on the .environment file.
>   Loading application.yml

And here is the script where the error occurs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'
require_relative '../app/models/environment.rb'
config = Environment.config('application')

exec "bundle exec pumactl --control-url tcp://127.0.0.1:#{config['control_port']} --control-token #{config['control_token']} phased-restart"
```

Connecting via [Putty](https://www.putty.org/), when I run the same command it gets executed without any problems.

*EDIT*

The PATH variable is different when I Putty:

> /home/csrhub/.rbenv/shims:/home/csrhub/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

And when I run with net-ssh PATH is:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Don't `cd` -- Just run `/home/csrhub/git/csrhub-api/bin/restart`

Comment: @Zak Same, still doesn't work. I get the same error :(

Comment: Check what is in the `.bashrc` on your server, it might have something ruby-specific. Replicate that to `.bash_profile`. There's a difference between running interactively and non-interactively.

Comment: @philpirozhkov

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NVhu3Wju6m4LpB_0EUwH9Gp7wnIbkXABq_DonR4oBvM/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I0rZw38WQBERqBIOGHbIK-za5bQB19h64MEjmH2vr1A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems like a `PATH` issue. The `PATH` for your `ssh-net` shell session is not the same as for your Putty session. This may be the reason the `bundle` command can not be found.

Comment: @Casper Yes, you  are right. But where does this difference come from and how to fix it?

Comment: This should get you running again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854055/net-ssh-and-remote-environment

Comment: @Casper

Still don't know how to load the missing paths to the PATH var. And how putty somehow loads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `ssh.exec!` call. `Net::SSH` does not use a *login shell* to run your commands. A login shell is [required for Bash to execute `.bash_profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/416931/823617).

Since your rbenv setup is in `.bash_profile`, your `exec!` call will be missing your full Ruby environment, and therefore running `bundle` later in you `restart` script will fail.

The solution should be to manually execute `.bash_profile`, so that rbenv gets loaded:

```
output = ssh.exec!("source ~/.bash_profile; ...rest of commands...")
```

More information and other proposals here:
[net-ssh and remote environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854055/net-ssh-and-remote-environment)